# Designing Block Diagrams For Control Systems

Tags: control-engineering, design, control-theory, systems-design

I'm looking for good software to design control systems, and more specifically to neatly design "block diagrams" for control systems.

Is there something like that?

Comment: Would Matlab/Simulink satisfy this?

Comment: I'm not sure, if it would I need a link to a tutorial or a guide because I'm not that familiar with Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Matlab Simulink.**

I think Simulink is the most satisfactory and easy way to build control systems with traditional block diagrams.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gs/simulink-block-diagrams.html

Some introductory block diagram models in Simulink:

http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=SimulinkControl

Example PID control block diagram with Matlab Simulink:

[image: PID control block diagram with Matlab Simulink]